# iOS equivalent to Ruby VCR Cassettes / recording server http response iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to record my http responses so my tests run faster. Ruby has a cool framework called VCR that you can use to record responses and load them for faster testing. Does iOS have anything similar? These are two pods that I've found but I was wondering if there was anything else (maybe native?)?

https://github.com/venmo/DVR

https://github.com/Velhotes/Vinyl

Thanks in advance!

Update:

So it turns out that you can't use DVR with AFNetworking. So instead I'm using OHHTTPStubs to stub the requests and SWHttpTrafficRecorder to try and record the traffic into files to be loaded later. But I'm having issues getting SWHttpTrafficRecorder to record the requests sent with AFHTTPSessionManager. I'm slowly coming to the conclusion that SWGtpTrafficRecorder and AFNetworking aren't compatible. Does anyone else have any suggestions for recording http requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using SWHttpTrafficRecorder to record traffic, but I had to implement method swizzling to record network requests from AFNetworking. Here's the link to the repo I forked off that has method swizzling implemented:

https://github.com/Amindv1/SWHttpTrafficRecorder

For stubbing I used OHHTTPStubs. These two pods are compatible, I've tested them and can confirm they work together. I also don't recommend using them for more than testing, I only include them in my test target.